# c++ How to count element frequency smartly?

Tags: c++, stl, frequency

I am getting array element [2 2 2 3 4 5 6]
I want the count of each element stored ? How to do in best way stl or something like that?

Comment: what do you mean by "best way"? optimise for time? space? coding difficulty? count of `#include`s?

Comment: `std::/*unordered_*/map<T, std::size_t>` ?

Comment: `std::unordered_multiset` and get the count of each key?

Comment: "smart" is not a desriable property of code btw, "simple" is much more important

Comment: If one of the provided answers works for you, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::map`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    std::map<int, int> occurrences;
    for (auto i : vec) occurrences[i]++;

    for (auto [element, count] : occurrences) {
        std::cout << element << " appeared " << count << " times\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the possible range of values is small and near 0:

```
std::array<size_t, max_value> histogram;
```

Otherwise

```
std::/*unordered_*/map<int, size_t> histogram;
```

And then

```
for (int value : elements) { ++histogram[value]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> histogram;

for (auto a : table) {
    ++histogram[a];
}

for(auto [val, count] : histogram) {
    std::cout << val << ' ' << count << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/avo6Wo