# C++ - How do I frequency count characters?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write code to store the unique characters and their frequencies in a dynamic array. I need to increase its size as new data comes in. New data in this case will be a new character that is encountered. The algorithm I have in mind is to check the list of known characters every single time I read from the given string. If it is a new character I need to increase the array size by 1. If it is not a new character I will increase its frequency. It is an array of struct letter (in the code below). The problem is that, I spent quite a lot of time with this and had issues with implementing it. So the question is how can I exactly implement it? Thank you spending time to help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#define ARR_LEN(arr) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

using namespace std;

struct unique_char {
    char character;
    int frequency;
};

int main() {
    int char_count;
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);

    struct unique_char* chars = new struct unique_char[100];

    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::map<char, int>` or a `std::unordered_map<char, int>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049909/c-how-to-count-element-frequency-smartly

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The question is mistitled, and the referenced dupe is a bad match for what OP is actually asking.

Comment: Side note: [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), added in C++17, is an elegant and safer replacement for the `ARR_LEN` macro. Note that neither will function if the array has been [decayed to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: @user4581301 `std::size` wont work with a pointer to dynamically allocated array (though the macro wont work as well)

Comment: Since characters have a limited encoding range, using an array would be more efficient and straight forward.  No need to use a linked list or other schema that `std::map` uses.  Simple indexing calculation into an array is more efficient.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews On the flip side, clean semantics are more useful long-term than efficiency unless there's a need for it.

Comment: @GianPaolo a map's the simplest, cleanest way to go. The comment about sadism was with respect to using `std::size` on a dynamically allocated array when `std::vector` could have been an option.

Comment: @user4581301 you are right, I didn't catch the meaning of your comment. Yes, if a student is able to use somehow `std::size`, it means it has already learned what is a `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in the comments, using `std::map` makes this fairly straightforward.

One of the "fun" things about map is that the indexing operator creates new values "on demand" with a initial value of `0` for ints. So the actual code is essentially one line: `chars[c] += 1;`

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  map<char, int> chars;

  string str;
  getline(cin, str);

  for(char c: str) {
    chars[c] += 1;
  }

  for(auto [character, frequency]: chars) {
      cout << character << " : " << frequency << "\n";
  }
}
```

**N.B.** There is one major difference between this and @ThomasMatthews's answer:

The map will only contain the characters that have been seen, whereas the array will contain `0`s for all characters that were never hit. Which approach you use should be based on which of the two are more useful to you.

Comment: Good solution. BTW, if you use "map", then in the output, the characters will be automatically sorted and displayed in alphabetic order. But, if you use "unordered_map", then in the output, the characters will NOT be sorted and displayed in alphabetic order. Also, for search operation, the time complexity is different between "map" and "unordered_map".

Comment: Also, perhaps, you don't need to write "using namespace std" at the top of the file as you already write "std::cout" at the end of the file. People say that "using namespace std" may include too many unnecessary header files. BTW, this code requires C++11 or C++17 to compile due to "for(auto [character, frequency]: chars )". I like your solution.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I wouldn't use `using namespace` ever personally, but I want to keep OPs code as is as much as possible so that they can read the answer more easily. (I do agree that in this context, the `std::` should be dropped from the cout, that was just a reflex).

Comment: @Job_September_2020 `for (auto [character, frequency]: chars)` requires C++17 due to use of a structured binding. For C++11 and C++14, you can use `for (auto &p: chars) { std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n"; }` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Pedantically, it should be `for(const auto& p: chars) {...}`

Comment: @Frank, Please help me with 2 questions. (1) By default, when you first insert a character into the map, is the frequency for that character automatically set to 0 always ? - ((2) BTW, unrelatedly, if you define an integer as "int a ; " without setting the initial value to 0, sometimes, it may have a default value that is NOT a zero ?)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 The map uses [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (this page covers both of your questions) in these scenarios, as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: @Job_September_2020 And to clarify wrt/ your second question, from the PoV of the language, the value of an uninitialized variable is not "0", or "sometimes not 0". The value **doesn't exist at all**, and attempting to read it is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Using an array makes things straight forward:

```
unsigned int frequencies[256] = {0};
while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
{
   const size_t length = str.length();
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
   {
       const char c = str[i];
       ++frequencies[c];
   }
}
```

Although, you may want to improve efficiency:

```
const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024u * 1024u;
//...
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
while (std::cin.read(&buffer[0], BUFFER_SIZE)
{
    const size_t chars_read = cin.gcount();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < chars_read; ++i)
    {
         const char c = buffer[i];
         ++frequencies[c];
    }
}
```

The above code uses block reading to improve input performance.  No scanning for newline characters, just read straight into memory.  Determine the frequencies from the characters in memory.

**Edit 1: `unsigned char`**
From the comments, an `unsigned char` may be a safer data type than `char` because `char` can be signed.  This may be an issue when accessing the array slots because a `signed char` could be negative and negative indices are usually a bad thing.  When you run it, if there are issues, replace the `char` type with `unsigned char`.

Comment: Maybe use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @doug:  The `const c` should be `const char c`.  The compiler will optimize out the temporary assignment and combine with the other statement.

Comment: Agree with @Dmitri `char` is dangerous unless it is known that the system implements it as unsigned. A `c` char, if it's signed like in x86, with the high order bit set will access outside of the array. At best it's UB.